# SendMessage кидает NullPointer

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Не могу понять почему в методе execute, где я вызываю свой метод `askAboutBrand()` вылетает `NullPointerException`. Когда я вызываю в execute `showGreetingMenu()` - все работает.

showGreetengMenu() выводит текст и 3 инлайн кнопки. Как только я нажму на кнопку с `callBackData = "1"` у меня должен появится текст из `askAboutBrand()`. Но как бы я не пробовал - получаю `null`

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    private final String BOT_NAME = "test_bot";
    private final String BOT_TOKEN = "";

    public Bot(DefaultBotOptions defaultBotOptions) {
        super(defaultBotOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        // Получаем текст сообщения
        if (update.hasMessage()) {
            String message = update.getMessage().getText();
            if (message != null) {
                if (message.startsWith("/start")) {
                    try {
                        execute(showGreetingMenu(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString()));
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
            if (update.getCallbackQuery().getData().startsWith("1")) {
                try {
                    SendMessage sendMessage = askAboutBrand(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString()); // Тут ломается
                    execute(sendMessage);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Метод, отвечающий за вывод приветственного меню. Содержит в себе текст и 3 кнопки
    private SendMessage showGreetingMenu(String chatId) {
        InlineKeyboardButton createAd = new InlineKeyboardButton();  // Создаем кнопку, которая отвечает за создание объявлений
        createAd.setText("Создать объявление");  // Присваиваем кнопке текст
        createAd.setCallbackData("1"); // Устанавливаем значение, которое придет после нажатия кнопки (Обязательно! Иначе Exception)
        InlineKeyboardButton showAd = new InlineKeyboardButton(); // Создаем кнопку, которая отвечает за показ объявлений
        showAd.setText("Показать объявления");
        showAd.setCallbackData("2");
        InlineKeyboardButton myAd = new InlineKeyboardButton(); // Создаем кнопку, которая отвечает за показ моих объявлений
        myAd.setText("Мои объявления");
        myAd.setCallbackData("3");

        // Создаем 2 ряда кнопок
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> firstRow = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> secondRow = new ArrayList<>();

        // В первом ряду 2 кнопки, а во втором 1
        firstRow.add(createAd);
        firstRow.add(showAd);
        secondRow.add(myAd);

        //Объединяем кнопки в одно целое для отправки
        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> inlineButtons = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                firstRow,
                secondRow
        ));

        InlineKeyboardMarkup markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        markup.setKeyboard(inlineButtons);

        SendMessage sendMessage = createMessage(chatId, "Тест");
        sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(markup);
        return sendMessage; // Возвращаем наше сообщение
    }

    public SendMessage createMessage(String chatId, String text) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setText(text);
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        return sendMessage;
    }


    public SendMessage askAboutBrand(String chatId) { // этот метод кидает ошибку
        return createMessage(chatId, "Введите бренд автомобиля");
    }

    public SendMessage askAboutModel(String chatId, int messageId) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setText("Введите модель автомобиля");
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(messageId);
        return sendMessage;
    }


    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return BOT_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return BOT_TOKEN;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (update.hasMessage()) {//<----
           ...
} else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
     askAboutBrand(update.getMessage()//<-----ничего странного?
}
```

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery

Не знаю что там у тебя за либа, но думаю что нужно как то так.

```
  update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage()
```

Comment: Боже, спасибо большое. Я только сегодня начала telegram api изучать и долго бился над этим